# numpy.where returning int instead of float

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

`numpy.where` is converting `float` array to `int`.

Using jupyter notebook

```
x = np.array([1.0, 2.3, 1.3, 2.9])
print(x)
print(np.where(x>.1))
```

I was expecting a result like this: `[1.0, 2.3, 1.3, 2.9]`. I am sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) gives you a list of indexes where the condition holds true. You would want to use those indexes in the actual array to get your elements

```
In [44]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                             

In [45]: x = np.array([1.0, 2.3, 1.3, 2.9])                                                                                                                                                             

In [47]: np.where(x>.1)                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[47]: (array([0, 1, 2, 3]),)

In [48]: x[np.where(x>.1)]                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[48]: array([1. , 2.3, 1.3, 2.9])
```